# detecting intersection of two disks using abaqus python

Tags: python, intersection, composite, particles, abaqus

I am working on modeling of a particulate composite using a Representative Volume Element (RVE) containing disk shaped random particles in abaqus python script. I want to add an algorithm in python script detecting intersection of any two different particles so I'll be able to avoid it. Does any one have an idea of how to write the algorithm?
Thanks all

Comment: you might add the computational geometry keyword. Is this 3d? Are the disks 2d?

Comment: Hi agentp. The disks have thickness so accounted as 3d. By computational geometry keyword, do you mean python modules such as shapely?or something else?

Comment: i mean the keywords at the bottom of your question.  A disk with thickness is called a cylinder, I imagine google searching intersecting cylinders would be useful.